# Upload ipa to hockeyapp via shell script in jenkins

Tags: shell, curl, jenkins, hockeyapp

I am writing following shell script for uploading `.ipa` to hockey app using **jenkins**.

```
curl \
    -F "status=2" \
    -F "notify=1" \
    -F "notes=Testing manual upload using cURL" \
    -F "notes_type=0" \
    -F "ipa=/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/jenkinadhocIPA/build/Release-iphoneos/artifact/abc.ipa" \
    -H "X-HockeyAppToken: 77009df19f344ddea16bbd827f706ea6" \
    https://rink.hockeyapp.net/manage/apps/781072/app_versions/new 
    | python -m json.tool
```

[image]

I am receiving the following error at console :

> 14:49:02 + curl -F status=2 -F notify=1 -F 'notes=Testing manual
>   upload using cURL' -F notes_type=0 -F
>   ipa=/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/jenkinadhocIPA/build/Release-iphoneos/artifact/abc.ipa
>   -H 'X-HockeyAppToken: 77009df19f344ddea16bbd827f706ea6' https://rink.hockeyapp.net/manage/apps/781072/app_versions/new
>   14:49:03   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time
>   Time  Current 14:49:03                                  Dload  Upload 
>   Total   Spent    Left  Speed 14:49:03   0     0    0     0    0     0 
>   0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0 100   753  100   106  100
>   647     51    315  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--   315 100   753  100
>   106  100   647     51    315  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--   315 14:49:05
>   You are being redirected./Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/jenkins3915686678610481595.sh:
>   line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `|'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to prefix the filename with `@` to have `curl` reference it as a file:

> This enables uploading of binary files etc. To force the 'content' part to be a file, prefix the file name with an @ sign.

https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-F